# How to prevent USB headset buttons to kill the mouse click handler?

Tags: usb, headset

I am running Xubuntu 14.04 on a Lenovo W530.

The other day we received brand new Plantronics Blackwire C420 headsets.

After a short while I realized that something was strange - and I nailed it down: the headset has 4 control buttons (volume up/down, mute, "phone"). When I press any of these buttons, the "mouse click handler" dies. This means: mouse clicks ... do not cause actions any more. If I unplug the headset; or close the application that is currently using the headset (like my SUT call window) everything goes back to normal.

I did some searching, found

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/993655?comments=all

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-evdev/+bug/1006156

The last link points to
http://www.helplinux.ru/wiki/en:kb:ubuntu-plantronics

That page gives an instruction for 13.10 / 14.04.

So I ran

> lsusb | grep -i plantronics
>       Bus 001 Device 006: ID 047f:aa14 Plantronics, Inc.

Then I ran

> sudo evtest 
>   (I selected the headset and pressed phone / volume up / volume down /
>   mute on / mute off and got)

```
Event: time 1421919129.677039, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value b0020
Event: time 1421919129.677039, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 256 (BTN_0), value 1
Event: time 1421919129.677039, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1421919132.913033, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value ffa000b2
Event: time 1421919132.913033, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 261 (BTN_5), value 1
Event: time 1421919132.913033, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 261 (BTN_5), value 0
Event: time 1421919132.913033, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value ffa000f8
Event: time 1421919132.913033, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 266 (?), value 0
Event: time 1421919132.913033, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value ffa000f9
Event: time 1421919132.913033, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 267 (?), value 0
Event: time 1421919132.913033, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1421919133.959032, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value ffa000b1
Event: time 1421919133.959032, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 260 (BTN_4), value 1
Event: time 1421919133.959032, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 260 (BTN_4), value 0
Event: time 1421919133.959032, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1421919135.896964, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value b002f
Event: time 1421919135.896964, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 257 (BTN_1), value 1
Event: time 1421919135.896964, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1421919139.744963, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value b002f
Event: time 1421919139.744963, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 257 (BTN_1), value 0
Event: time 1421919139.744963, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```

Then I followed the instruction from the Russian page and created

> cat /etc/udev/rules.d/49-plantronics.rules

```
ACTION!="add|change", GOTO="xorg_plantronics_end"
KERNEL!="event*", GOTO="xorg_plantronics_end"

SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ENV{ID_BUS}=="", IMPORT{builtin}="usb_id"

ENV{ID_VENDOR_ID}=="047f", ENV{ID_MODEL_ID}=="aa14", ENV{ID_INPUT_KEY}="1", ENV{ID_INPUT_KEYBOARD}="1"
```

Plus:

> cat /etc/udev/hwdb.d/50-keyboard.hwdb

```
keyboard:usb:v047FpAA14*
KEYBOARD_KEY_ffa000b1=volumeup
KEYBOARD_KEY_ffa000b2=volumedown
KEYBOARD_KEY_b002f=micmute
KEYBOARD_KEY_b0020=phone
```

Finally I ran ... sudo udevadm hwdb --update ; sudo udevadm control --reload ... and I also rebooted.

Long story short: it doesn't help. When pressing any of the buttons, the mouse click handler still goes away. Interestingly enough, coworker is running same hardware with Gnome3 ... and he doesn't have this problem ;-(

Any thoughts, ideas, suggestions are welcome (expect "use Gnome3 instead of xubuntu").
For example I am wondering if there any log files that would tell me if these udef control files have any effect, or are malformed, ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lesson learned here: always read the complete launchpad bug description.
There was one comment pointing out to modify /etc/X11/xorg.conf and add

```
Section "InputClass"

    Identifier "Plantronics"

    MatchVendor "Plantronics"

    Option "Ignore" "true"

EndSection
```

Did that; removed the UDEV files and rebooted.

Afterwards the headset (including the buttons) is fully functional; and no mouse clicking issues any more.

Comment: Late comment, but just wanted to say, that this works for me as well :)

Comment: You are very much welcome!

Comment: Finally! I can mute my microphone *and* use the mouse!

Comment: @fuenfundachtzig Thanks for the surprising upvote. Always glad when my stuff helps other folks!